# Discord.py - Remove all users from 1 role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I posted yesterday already due my problem, but we could not solve it.

I have following code

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import discord

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', help_command=None)


@client.command()
async def swipe(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    for member in role.members:
        await member.remove_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"Successfully removed all members from {role.mention}.")


@client.command()
async def add(ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.Member):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"**Successfully give {role.mention} to {user.mention}.**")


@client.command()
async def remove(ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.Member):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await user.remove_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"**Successfully removed {role.mention} from {user.mention}.**")



client.run('censored')
```

My command "add" and "remove" works perfectly.
My command "swipe" does not want to work.
The bot has administration permissions, and the selected role is in the hierarchy below the bot.

I also added `if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:` to check if there's a problem, but it changed nothing.

I won't get any error in my trace back, but the users are still in the role after I use this command "swipe".

To rule out error I also created a new Discord-Server with another user and tried it there. Same result.

Whats wrong with my command?

```
 @client.command()
    async def swipe(ctx, role: discord.Role):
        for member in role.members:
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            await ctx.send(f"Successfully removed all members from {role.mention}.")
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `role.members` actually contains any users? Member caching is unreliable at times, especially without the priviledged members intent

Comment: At the moment there are 3 users at the role "test".

Comment: Do all three of them show up when you do something like `print(role.members)`?

Comment: I added `await ctx.send(role.members)` and as a result, I get an empty list.

Comment: There's your issue, then. You could try enabling the privileged members intent (if your bot is in 100 or more servers, this requires verification and whitelisting by Discord staff). That should populate the guild's member cache and subsequently the `role.members` list

Comment: Okay i enabled if now in the dashboard, but where exactly i have to add code to my bot in this case? Thank you so much !

Comment: I'll write up a full answer to address all the discussion in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments, the issue is the `role.members` list not being populated. This can be fixed by enabling the [privileged members intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#member-intent). Note that this requires verification and whitelisting by Discord staff, if your bot is in 100 or more servers.

To use the additional intents with your bot, you need to first enable the intent for your bot in your [discord developers profile](https://discord.com/developers/applications/). Once that is done, add the intents to your bot client like so

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', help_command=None, intents=intents)
```

With this, your server's member cache (and subsequently your `role.members` list) should be populated on startup, allowing your command to work properly

---

On a side note, you probably want to move the confirmation message line one indentation level out, or else the bot will send a message after each member it removed from the role

```py
@client.command()
async def swipe(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    for member in role.members:
        await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully removed all members from {role.mention}.")
```